# ggplot geom_histogram with different colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create histogram with ggplot2 package in R and add vertical lines to show the mean-sd and mean+sd.

I am using below codes

```
iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length)) + geom_histogram() + theme_bw() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = mean(iris$Sepal.Length) - sd(iris$Sepal.Length), linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = mean(iris$Sepal.Length), linetype = "solid") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = mean(iris$Sepal.Length) + sd(iris$Sepal.Length), linetype = "dashed")
```

It works perfectly. Is there any way to add different color for each group?

For example, scores that are below mean - sd with orange color and score that are above mean + sd with red color.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is OK, just you have to add `fill=Species` within `aes` like

```
iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, fill=Species)) + geom_histogram() + theme_bw() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = mean(iris$Sepal.Length) - sd(iris$Sepal.Length), linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = mean(iris$Sepal.Length), linetype = "solid") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = mean(iris$Sepal.Length) + sd(iris$Sepal.Length), linetype = "dashed")
```

[image]
Is this what you want?

## Update

```
iris$value<-cut(iris$Sepal.Length, c(min(iris$Sepal.Length)-1, mean(iris$Sepal.Length) - sd(iris$Sepal.Length), mean(iris$Sepal.Length) + sd(iris$Sepal.Length), max(iris$Sepal.Length)),
              labels = c("< Mean - SD","Mean",">  Mean + SD"))

iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, fill=value)) + geom_histogram() + theme_bw() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = mean(iris$Sepal.Length) - sd(iris$Sepal.Length), linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = mean(iris$Sepal.Length), linetype = "solid") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = mean(iris$Sepal.Length) + sd(iris$Sepal.Length), linetype = "dashed")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This is useful, however, this is not the required result that I am looking for. As you can see in above example, values that are below 5 (mean-sd) have three colors (red, blue, green). More precisely, I want each category to have exactly same color.

Comment: Thank you @BappaDas, the updated codes work perfectly.